# Can I use -k 3 -t instead of -k3n in Linux?

Tags: linux

In order to modify a file called `oldfile` and change all occurrences of the `!` to a `:`. The command string must also sort the file numerically on the GID field and then save the output to a file called `newfile`.

I used

```
sed 's/\!/\:/g' oldfile | sort -t: -k3n > ~/newfile
```

Can I use

```
sed 's/\!/\:/g' oldfile | sort -t: -k 3 -t > ~/newfile
```

instead of the above command?

Comment: Have you read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) for `sort`?

Comment: You need the `n` modifier if you want numeric sorting. And `-t` requires an argument after it.

Comment: Why do you want to use a second `-t` option without an argument?